# Is this a problem that a pool found 6 consecutive blocks?

Tags: mining-pools

Check this out:

[image: six blocks made by single pool]

The pool will not make the 51% attack of course, for they are counting money on the system;
but it's still a problem right?

Answer (score 5):

It would be a statistical anomaly if this did *not* happen from time to time.

With pools having over 20% or so, they're bound to find 6+ consecutive blocks every now and then.

It's not a problem. They can't really abuse or corrupt the system like this, especially since they can't plan for this sort of thing to happen on purpose. Even if they'd have 30%, it's still a rare phenomenon (like less than once in a thousand tries).

Comment: I saw an equation once about the attack money/mingpower cost,but I lost it;Man,this "like less than once in a thousand tries" ,is it in an equation too?

Comment: If you have 30% chance of finding a block, you have 0.3^6 = 0.000729 or once in 1371 chance to find 6 consecutive blocks. But again, even if someone *does* find 6 blocks, it's still not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a problem. Bitcoin is secure and Discus Fish is a well known pool. From time to time, maths tells us that this should happen. It is rare but with 21 million bitcoin to find it must happen at least once! It would be impossible to hack the system like this as there was nothing to hack before; the bitcoins didn't exist!

Comment: There is no '21 million blocks to find'. 21 million BTC has nothing to do with 21 million blocks.